# Splunk Role Validation for dashboard creation

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Which capability i should add/delete from  any role  if i don't want to give access to create dashboard to that role say splunk_user ..
Below capability doesn't help 
Splunk_user => edit_per_panel_filters

kindly suggest..

Answer (score 0):

A user can create their own dashboards in an app, but no other user can access it. Thats the same for all knowledge objects. A power user can change the permissions of dashboards (and other knowledge objects) which can make a dashboard accessible by all users, wihthin an app

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Knowledge/Manageknowledgeobjectpermissions#Restrict_knowledge_object_access_by_app_and_role